# Route specific port traffic through a VPN on Asus router

Tags: vpn, router, port, asus

I own a ac88u and would like to have a specific port on a specific machine within my network to always go through my VPN.
I can get an open VPN file to configure the router if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/wiki/Policy-based-routing

Guess I will have to go through setting up custom firmware because the stock one doesn't allow what I want to do.